# Android app crashes without internet connection?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, android-internet

I am using parse backend service in my Android app. The problem I am facing is coding for push notification. Many times when there is no internet connection on the mobile device , an automatical alert appears "Unfortunately your app has stopped", without even using it or running in background/foreground. Please help.

This is the logcat:

```
Unable to start service com.parse.PushService@1658046d with Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION flg=0x10 pkg=com.grubcha.grubproject cmp=com.grubcha.grubproject/com.parse.PushService (has extras) }: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(Context) before using the Parse library.
```

Comment: it would be nice to see the actual code or at least error message from LogCat, otherwise we would not know where to start

Comment: i have updated with the logical please help.

Comment: it seems you did not initialize Parse in your Application class.

Answer (score 0):

Add your keys to `Application.java`:

```
Parse.initialize(this, "APPLICATION ID", "CLIENT KEY");
```

See here : [Parse quickstart](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new)

Comment: Sorry, the problem is just about push notification.